# How to change "File Upload" dialog's Title in a browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, firefox

Is it possible to change the title of "File Upload" dialogs in any common browser such as IE or FireFox?

[image]

[image]

Comment: As i know then i think you can't change these dialogs titles, And another alternative for not displaying these title, you can use drag and drop file upload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking the documentation pages I cannot find such a thing... I guess this is not possible.

In the [*Control types*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#input-control-types) from the *Forms* section we find [the `input[type='file']`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#file-select) that is described as:

> **file select**
>
> This control type allows the user to select files so that
>   their contents may be submitted with a form. The [INPUT](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#edef-INPUT) element is used
>   to create a file select control.

Then we check the [*Input elements*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#edef-INPUT) and we find a list of the elements with different types that uses `input`:

There is the `file` type too:

> **file**
>
> Creates a [file select](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#file-select) control. User agents may use the value of
>   the value attribute as the initial file name.

So, in conclusion this is unfortunately not possible.

---

The alternatives you can choose are to use drag and drop on a popup that is opened inside of the HTML:

```
-------------------------------------- <-- the full page
|                                    |   
|                                    |   
|       |----------------| <------------ The popup
|       | Your title     |           |   
|       |----------------|           |   
|       | Drag files here|           |   
|       |----------------|           |   
|                                    |   
|                                    |   
--------------------------------------
```

Comment: is there still no way to archieve this even w/ the new html5-file api?

Comment: I guess this is still not possible -- just googled a little, but couldn't find anything. If someone has a solution, ping me. Right now, i think the browser handles that.

Comment: i couldn't find anything either... :'(

Comment: I also couldn't find anything as of  June 2017