# Customize file dialog

Tags: javascript, html

It's possible to customize the file open dialog launched via clicking an `input` element? For example, I want to change the dialog title **Open File** and put an arbitrary text there. It's possible to achieve this using HTML/JS?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't think that is customizable, but is a good question though.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19944430/how-to-change-file-upload-dialogs-title-in-a-browser

Comment: Indeed, @Dale it's duplicated...I'll close this, thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change "File Upload" dialog's Title in a browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19944430/how-to-change-file-upload-dialogs-title-in-a-browser)