# Html input file: how to change default window title?

Tags: html, css, html-input

I am working on an old version of IE and wonder if I can change the title of file selection window. The tag below

```
<input type="file" name="myFile" />
```

shows a button of "Browse...", when clicked a file selection window pops out with title "Choose File to Upload". I would like to change this title.

Comment: Apparently there's a hacky way to do it. [This post might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138719/change-default-text-in-input-type-file).

Comment: It's hardcoded into IE, or in to any browser. There may not be a way to change it from the point of view of the page.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change "File Upload" dialog's Title in a browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19944430/how-to-change-file-upload-dialogs-title-in-a-browser)